# Rails SVG partial render breaks after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg

I have just upgraded Rails from 5.2 to 7.0. In other words, I ran the upgrade process three times:

- 5.2 to 6.0
- 6.0 to 6.1
- 6.1 to 7.0

having first upgraded Ruby from 2.6.8 to 3.0.6.

In addition to a bunch of other challenges (eg. my `routes.rb` and `assets.rb` were emptied), this broke all my SVG partial renders.

The previous code such as:

`<%= render "pages/AU-map.svg" %>`

had to be rewritten as

`<%= render partial: "pages/AU-map", formats: [:svg] %>`

Can anyone explain why this is and where this required change is documented?

FWIW, https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render mentions that `:formats` is an option for `render` but https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.1/classes/ActionController/Rendering.html#method-i-render doesn't list it as an option.